# Why is there a webpack.config.js file in multiple levels of a package?

Tags: node.js, github, reactjs, scrollbar, webpack

I look at many projects on Github to learn through the examples, but one thing that confuses me is when you have a package that is multiple directories deep and has webpack.config.js files in multiple levels of the directory tree.

From my understanding webpack is bundling up all the js code and making it watchable. I don't understand how multiple bundlings would work out.

For example https://github.com/ojame/react-scrollbars

On the top level you have a package.json and a webpack.config.js(So I think oh this is where I run npm install and then webpack)

But I want to see the examples in the "examples" directory and there is another webpack.config.js, which is confusing to my webpack newbie brain.

What's up with this? Where do I do my bundling to check out this resource? Maybe using the example above would illustrate the solution well.

Answer (score 0):

Examples often behave like their own repository. They show how you, as a consumer, would use the package. Because you would have your own webpack config, so do the examples.